# Any way to read images from clipboard in an MV3 Chrome Extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I am trying to read an image from the clipboard within a popup of a Manifest V3 Chrome Extension.

The clipboard API does not work in popups for me; it simply hangs similarly to how it does in a [service worker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1160302). In addition to those two, I tried messaging a content script which would try to retrieve data from the clipboard, but it does not work either because it is not focused when the user is in the popup. For similar reasons, I can't inject a script dynamically. I am aware of the trick of creating a textarea, pasting into it, and reading the value, but it does not work because I want to read images from the clipboard rather than text. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's https://crbug.com/1337152. You'll have to add a button to the page or open a new window with your extension's page.html and then read the clipboard inside.